# Show two textbox text into the third

Tags: javascript, html

I have three `textbox`. Now what I want is,

I want to show the two texbox text with **/** into the third box.

I tried like this.

```
function CombineValueText() {
        var txtfirst = document.getElementById('txtSurvey1').value;
        var txtSecond = document.getElementById('txtHissa').value;

        var result = parseInt(txtfirst) / parseInt(txtSecond);
        if (!isNaN(result)) {
            document.getElementById('txt712_1').value = result;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('txt712_1').value = result;
        }
    }
```

but it is dividing both the values and showing.

Here is the html

```
<td class="label">
    Survey No :
</td>
<td class="field">
    <input name="txtSurvey1" type="text" id="Text1" onkeyup="CombineValueText()" onblur="FunDupCheck()"
        style="width: 80%;" />
</td>
<td class="label">
    Hissa No :
</td>
<td class="field">
    <input name="txtHissa" type="text" id="Text2" onkeyup="CombineValueText()" style="width: 80%;" />
</td>
<td class="label">
    7/12 :
</td>
<td class="field">
    <input name="txt712_1" type="text" id="Text3" readonly="readonly" style="width: 30%" />
</td>
```

Comment: Get rid of parseint and string concat the slash

Comment: You're also attempting to use `getElementById` with the `name` attributes of your inputs. You'll need to use the `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write this:

```
var result = parseInt(txtfirst) / parseInt(txtSecond);
```

It automatically gets calculated, and you are also checking if the output is `!isNaN(result)`, which doesn't make any sense. I guess you are looking for displaying it as string. So get rid of the `if` condition and make the `result` to look like a string:

```
var result = parseInt(txtfirst) + "/" + parseInt(txtSecond);
```

And you should just have:

```
document.getElementById('txt712_1').value = result;
```

Also, you don't need the `parseInt`, which is used only for calculation. Technically you are combining the two strings with a `/`:

```
var result = txtfirst + "/" + txtSecond;
```

One more thing is, you need to use the `id` values for `getElementById`, so change it to:

```
var txtfirst = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
var txtSecond = document.getElementById('Text2').value;
```

```
document.getElementById('Text3').value = result;
```

**Final Code**

```js
function CombineValueText() {
  var txtfirst = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
  var txtSecond = document.getElementById('Text2').value;

  var result = txtfirst + "/" + txtSecond;
  document.getElementById('Text3').value = result;
}

function FunDupCheck() {
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">
      Survey No :
    </td>
    <td class="field">
      <input name="txtSurvey1" type="text" id="Text1" onkeyup="CombineValueText()" onblur="FunDupCheck()" style="width: 80%;" />
    </td>
    <td class="label">
      Hissa No :
    </td>
    <td class="field">
      <input name="txtHissa" type="text" id="Text2" onkeyup="CombineValueText()" style="width: 80%;" />
    </td>
    <td class="label">
      7/12 :
    </td>
    <td class="field">
      <input name="txt712_1" type="text" id="Text3" readonly="readonly" style="width: 30%" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```